# HGETALL in Redis-cli showing the results like x00 xff. What is really happening?

Tags: redis, redis-cache

I successfully did insert values to my redis cache and when trying to get the values that is stored, I am getting values like

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL UPGRADE_ME
1) "\xfc\r-447340129694"
2) "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00S\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x010com.customer.upgrade.Key\x00\xfd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd0\xbe@\xff\x00\x10\x00\xff\xfc\x04time\xff\xff\xfc\x06reason\x00"
```

Are the values getting stored as `binary`? Also how can I make it store as `json`.?

My java code looks like

```
    RMapCache<String, Key> keys= redissonClient.getMapCache(UPGRADE_ME);
    keys.put(key1, obj, cacheProperties.getProps(),
                TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Surely you have the code that put the values into Redis?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389158/does-redis-only-allow-string-representation-but-not-numeric-value

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes . I am using the reddison java client

Answer (score 0):

There are APIs to pass the codec and we can pass `org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec()` for storing objects as json

```
 RMapCache<String, Key> keys= redissonClient.getMapCache(UPGRADE_ME,new org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec());
 keys.put(key1, obj, cacheProperties.getProps(),
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```